# Why can't I modify DataFrame in place by selecting some columns when iterating through list of DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
dfl = [pd.DataFrame(
     {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": pd.Timestamp("20130102"),
         "C": pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype="float32"),
         "D": "foo",
     }
)]
for df in dfl:
  df = df[["A", "B"]]
print(dfl)
```

I was expecting the output has only column "A" and "B" since I was modifying the DataFrame in place (`df = ...`). However I got:

```
[     A          B    C    D
0  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo
1  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo
2  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo
3  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo]
```

What is the reason and how can I **select** (not drop) some columns from the each DataFrame in that list in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `df` is a local pointer to the loop. By doing `df = df[['A','B']]`, you tell the pointer to point to something new, which doesn't override the existing element of the list. Another similar example:

```py
ll = [[1]]
for l in ll:
    l = None
print(ll)
# output: [[1]]
```

To override the element, you would want to do:

```
for i, d in enumerate(dfl):
    dfl[i] = d[['A','B']]

print(dfl)
```

Out:

```
[     A          B
0  1.0 2013-01-02
1  1.0 2013-01-02
2  1.0 2013-01-02
3  1.0 2013-01-02]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this output because you are not assigning it back:

```
fl = [pd.DataFrame(
     {
        "A": 1.0,
        "B": pd.Timestamp("20130102"),
         "C": pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype="float32"),
         "D": "foo",
     }
)]
for x in dfl:
  x = df[["A", "B"]]  # you see values are assigned to x not dfl
  print(x)   # just printing to make it clear; x has 2 columns A and B now
  print(dfl)  # just printing to make it clear; dfl still has 4 columns A,B,C,D

#outputs
     A          B
0  1.0 2013-01-02
1  1.0 2013-01-02
2  1.0 2013-01-02
3  1.0 2013-01-02

[     A          B    C    D
0  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo
1  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo
2  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo
3  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  foo]
```

So, if you want the desired result then:

```
for df in dfl:
  dfl = df[["A", "B"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
[df[['A', 'B']] for df in dfl]
```

---

This is basic python problem, same for strings

```
lst = ['abc', 'cd']
for i in lst:
  i = i[0]
```

`lst`

```
['abc', 'cd']
```

---

```
[i[0] for i in lst]
```

output :

```
['a', 'c']
```